# Responsive Image with CSS for smaller screens

Tags: css, html

I have two horrizontal tab images. I am moving my web application to display it in mobile.So I used responsive web design. I want the two horrizntal images to display inline. But when the screen width decreases, the second image is moving down. The image shrinks after moving down. I want the images shrink before moving down and it should not move down.CSS and HTML is given below.Please help.

```
.image-wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

<figure>
    <img class="image-wrapper" src="~/Images/Q.gif" />
    <img class="image-wrapper" src="~/Images/H.gif" />
    </figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using Media query. Try something like this:

```
@media (max-width : 320px) {

  .image-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width : 320px) {
  .image-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

As seen from the code, the tipping point beyond which the images will flow one below the other is when the available width is less than 480px.

Comment: I am using media queries only. The images is getting shrinked when i resize the window, that means,the css is working. But still I am not getting the result.

Comment: Till width of 480 it works already. I want it for a much smaller screen size around 320 for apple phones

Comment: @user2707092 so you wish to change into a single column layout when the width is 320px or less? Then just change the `480px` in the sample code I posted to `320px`. See my edited post.

Comment: I tired that already.But no luck. If I use only one image,it works fine.It shrinks,but for 2 images it goes down

Comment: I don't get it. Just [**fiddled**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/DPsC9/) it for you. Try re-sizing the Result container and notice the layout changing when the width falls below 320px. Just added `float:left` for the images to float side-by-side. You can also try reducing the width from `50%` to `49.5%`.

Comment: Working now. thanks Vikram..I think float left has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try using [media queries](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width), they will only apply to smaller screens

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 760px) {
     img{
        width: 100%;
     }
 }
```